# Calling a Sinatra app instance method from TestCase

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I have an util method into a *Sinatra* application and I would like to tested from my `TestCase`.

The problem is that I don't know how to invoke it, if I just use `app.util_method` I have the error `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'util_method' for #<Sinatra::ExtendedRack:0x007fc0c43305b8>`

#### my_app.rb:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  # [...] routes methods

  # utils methods
  def util_method
    return "hi"
  end
end
```

#### my_app_test.rb:

```
require "my_app.rb"
require "test/unit"
require "rack/test"

class MyAppTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    MyApp.new
  end

  # [...] routes methods tests

  def test_util_method
    assert_equal( "hi", app.util_method )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sinatra [aliases the `new` method to `new!`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1369-1370) before redefining it, so the simplest solution is to use that instead:

```
def app
  MyApp.new!
end
```

Of course I only noticed that *after* I’d come up with the following, which I’ll leave in as it could be useful/informative.

---

A possible way to get round Sinatra [redefining the `new` method and returning a complete Rack app](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1372-1377) a get hold of an instance your actual base class is to do what the “real” `new` method does yourself:

```
def app
  a = MyApp.allocate
  a.send :initialize
  a
end
```

This is a bit of a hack, but it might be useful for testing.

Another technique would be to “walk” the middleware stack until you got to your class. The following is a little fragile, as it depends on all the middleware involved to use the name `@app` to refer to the next app in the stack, but this is fairly common.

```
def app
  a = MyApp.new
  while a.class != MyApp
    a = a.instance_variable_get(:@app)
  end
  a
end
```

That won’t work on the yet to be released Sinatra 1.4 though (at least not on the current master, which is [commit 41840746e866e8e8e9a0eaafc53d8b9fe6615b12](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/tree/41840746e866e8e8e9a0eaafc53d8b9fe6615b12)), as `new` now returns a [`Wrapper` class](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/41840746e866e8e8e9a0eaafc53d8b9fe6615b12/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1767-1787) and the loop never ends. In this case you can grab the base class directly from the `@instance` variable:

```
def app
  MyApp.new.instance_variable_get :@instance
end
```

(note this last technique may well change before the final 1.4 release).

Comment: Thanks for your work and explanations. The `MyApp.new!` works perfectly and I don't obtain any side-effect in the rest of my tests. Still I don't fell confortable due it looks like this is not the way Sinatra wants you to work. Anyhow I think this is the most useful answer I'm gonna obtain.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are encountering is, that MyApp.new does not return an instance of MyApp but an instance of the middleware wrapping your App (usually Rack::Head or Sinatra::ShowExceptions). A good explanation can be found in the thread [Sinatra Usage Question / Rack App](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sinatrarb/Xbn6RYm2qT8).

The only solution I can think of is to change your instance method to a class method which can be called without the instance itself. As the instance of your App may be freshly instantiated for every request, an instance method probably doesn't have much advantages over a class method in your scenario.

**Edit:**

In the upcoming Sinatra 1.4 the initialization will change. Sinatra::Base.new will return a Sinatra::Wrapper instance, which exposes #settings and #helpers. This may help solve the problem of accessing Sinatra::Base instance methods. See the [Sinatra Changelog](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/CHANGES) for more information.

Comment: It is a solution for a portion of cases, but there are several others where the _util method_ can't be a _class method_ if for example I'm doing something related with the actual request like `def parse_params; puts "do stuff with the params: #{params}" end`

Comment: I just went through the Sinatra changelog and saw the following change which might help solve your problem: "Sinatra::Base.new now returns a Sinatra::Wrapper instance, exposing #settings and #helpers, yet going through the middleware stack on #call."
https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/CHANGES